# auto-py-to-exe компиляция с файлами настроек txt

Tags: python, компиляция, txt, auto-py-to-exe

Подскажите пожалуйста, компилирую файл **main.py** в exe с помощью **auto-py-to-exe**
В коде есть файлы настроек в формате txt, сделал это для возможности замены пути исполняемых файлов.
После компиляции программа работает, но при внесении изменений в файлах *txt*, программа информацию из
них не цепляет. Соответственно ***вопрос***, как сделать, чтобы компилированный файл **main.exe** получал информацию из файлов *1С.txt, 2С.txt, 3С.txt* (внутри файлов просто прописаны пути к файлам для исполнения, например C:\Programms\1C.xlsx)

````
from tkinter import Button, Label, Tk, messagebox, font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Выход из приложения", "Хотите выйти из приложения?"):
        master.destroy()

def run_1C():
    with open("С:\\Projects\\Lenta\\Settings\\1C.txt", "r") as file:
        program_paths = file.readlines()
        for program_path in program_paths:
            program_path = program_path.strip()
            if os.path.exists(program_path):
                os.startfile(program_path)
                print(f"Запуск программы: {program_path}")
            else:
                print(f"Файл не найден: {program_path}")
def run_2C():
    with open("С:\\Projects\\Lenta\\Settings\\2C.txt", "r") as file:
        program_paths = file.readlines()
        for program_path in program_paths:
            program_path = program_path.strip()
            if os.path.exists(program_path):
                os.startfile(program_path)
                print(f"Запуск программы: {program_path}")
            else:
                print(f"Файл не найден: {program_path}")
def run_3C():
    with open("С:\\Projects\\Lenta\\Settings\\3C.txt", "r") as file:
        program_paths = file.readlines()
        for program_path in program_paths:
            program_path = program_path.strip()
            if os.path.exists(program_path):
                os.startfile(program_path)
                print(f"Запуск программы: {program_path}")
            else:
                print(f"Файл не найден: {program_path}")
# create a tkinter window
master = Tk()

master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
image = Image.open("C:\\Projects\\Lenta\\FON.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
w = Label(master, image=photo)
# w.pack()
w.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
master.title("Lenivetz")
master.resizable(False, False)
# tk.resizable(0, 0)
master.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
master.iconbitmap("C:\\Projects\\Lenta\\Znak.ico")
master.geometry('1699x890')
# master['background']='#66CCCC'
# Create a Button
button = Button(master,
                text='Report 3C',
                font="Courier 20",
                bg='#7695f9',
                activebackground='#17FF17',
                command=run_3C).pack(fill='x', padx=[40, 80], pady=50)

button2 = Button(master,
                text='Report 2C',
                font="Courier 20",
                bg='#c773de',
                activebackground='#17FF17',
                 command=run_2C).pack(fill='x', padx=[40, 80], pady=50)

button3 = Button(master,
                text='1C: Loading',
                font="Courier 20",
                bg='yellow',
                activebackground='#17FF17',
                command=run_1C).pack(fill='x', padx=[40, 80], pady=50)

master.mainloop()```
````